# Let user update their password without current password in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am on rails 4.2.1 and devise 3.4.1. I basically want 2 things at same time:

[Allow users to edit their password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)

and

[Allow users to edit their account without providing a password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

I managed to have them working separately. But *solution 1* for the first problem seems to be, I'm afraid, incompatible with the only official solution for the second problem because, for the latter, I need to override the *registration* controller.

Hence I tried to do the *solution 1* job in the *registration* controller rather than the *application* one:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  protected

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

end
```

This way only added attribute like *name* get updated  while password is completely filtered out. 
I am not sure I should start an heavy customization as in *solutions 2 and 3* for such a simple aim.. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your `registrations_controller`:

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

And override the `update_withour_password` method on your user model or the model that uses Devise:

```
def update_without_password(params, *options)
  if params[:password].blank?
    params.delete(:password)
    params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
  end

  result = update_attributes(params, *options)
  clean_up_passwords
  result
end
```

---

Official docs/code - [database_authenticatable](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L117)

Answer (score 5):

After digging in devise code I found out that [update_without_password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L96-97) removes on purpose `:password` and `:password_confirmation` params. This is done by default for security reasons.

So the (maybe risky) solution was to override *update_without_password* in my resource model as it is but without removing *passwords** params

Comment: This helped me too. i am not sure if there is any harm in not removing password params when overriding  update_without_password except that I may end up having issues when I actually need to  use update_without_password for updating any other account details without the passwords.  
Thought?

Answer (score 3):

latest rails 6 solution:

```
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update(params)
  end
```